# Prob. 1, Sec. 27, in Munkres' TOPOLOGY, 2nd ed: How to show that the compactness of every closed interval implies the least upper bound property?

Tags: general-topology, compactness

Here is Prob. 1, Sec. 27, in the book *Topology* by James R. Munkres, 2nd edition:

> Prove that if $X$ is an ordered set in which every closed interval is compact, then $X$ has the least upper bound property.

My Attempt:

> Let $A$ be any non-empty subset of $X$ such that $A$ is bounded above in $X$; let $U$ be the set of all the upper bounds in $X$ of this set $A$. Then $U$ is also a non-empty subset of $X$.
>
> Case 1.
>
> If $A \cap U \not= \emptyset$, let us suppose that $v \in A \cap U$.
>
> Now as $v \in U$, so $v$ is an upper bound of the set $A$, by our definition of the set $U$.
>
> Also, as every element of $U$ is an upper bound of the set $A$ and as $v \in A$, so we must have 
>   $$ v \leq u \ \mbox{ for every element }  u \in U. $$
>
> Thus $v$ is an upper bound of the set $A$ and $v \leq u$ for every upper bound $u$ of $A$. Therefore $v$ is the least upper bound of the set $A$.
>
> Case 2.
>
> Let us now suppose that $A \cap U = \emptyset$.
>
> Then for every element $a \in A$ and for every element $u \in U$, we must have $a < u$.
>
> Let $a \in A$ and $u \in U$ be arbitrary. Then $a < u$. Moreover, the closed interval $[a,u]$ is compact, by our hypothesis.
>
> Let $\mathscr{L}$ be the collection of all the closed intervals of the form  $[x, y]$, where  $x \in A$, $y \in U$, and $[x,y] \subset [a,u]$. That is, let 
>   $$ \mathscr{L} \colon= \big\{ \ [x, y] \ \colon \ x \in A, y \in U, a \leq x < y \leq u \ \big\}. \tag{*} $$
>   Then the interval $[a, u]$ itself is in $\mathscr{L}$ so that $\mathscr{L}$ is non-empty.
>
> If $\left[x_1, y_1 \right], \ldots, \left[x_n, y_n \right]$ be any finite subcollection of $\mathscr{L}$, then we have 
>   $$ \bigcap_{j=1}^n \left[ x_j, y_j \right] = \left[ x_0, y_0 \right], $$
>   where 
>   $$ x_0 \colon= \max \left\{ x_1, \ldots, x_n \right\}, \qquad \mbox{ and } \qquad y_0 \colon= \min \left\{ y_1, \ldots, y_n \right\}. $$
>   Thus $\bigcap_{j=1}^n \left[ x_j, y_j \right]$ is again an interval in $\mathscr{L}$ and is therefore non-empty.
>
> Then $\mathscr{L}$ is a collection of non-empty closed sets in $[a,u]$ such that $\mathscr{L}$ has the finite intersection property. Since $[a,u]$ is compact, therefore the intersection of all the closed intervals in $\mathscr{L}$ is non-empty, by Theorem 26.9 in Munkres.
>
> That is, there is an element $p \in [a,u]$ such that $p \in [x,y]$ for all $x \in A$ and for all $y \in U$ for which $[x,y] \subset [a,u]$. In particular, this $p \in [a, u]$ also, so that 
>   $$ a \leq p \leq u. \tag{1} $$
>
> But $a$ was chosen to be an arbitrary element of set $A$, and $u$ was chosen to be an arbitrary element of the set $U$ (i.e. $u$ was chosen to be an arbitrary upper bound for the set $A$).
>
> Thus the leftmost inequality in (1) implies that  $p$ is an upper bound of the set $A$, and the rightmost inequality in (1) implies that $p$ is also the *least* of all of the upper bounds of $A$.
>
> Hence $p$ is the *least upper bound* of the set $A$.
>
> But as $A$ was chosen to be an arbitrary non-empty subset of $X$ which was bounded above in $X$, so we can conclude that $X$ has the least upper bound property.

Is this proof correct? If so, is it clear enough? If not, then where are the issues?

Comment: Perhaps add a detail about how there is only one point $p$ and not a whole interval $[p_0,p_1]$. It's not very important, though.

Comment: @Arthur, please have a look at my post now; I've editted it to add the uniqueness part. How do you like the proof now?

Comment: You have to show $p \in U$ before you can conclude $[a, p] \in \mathscr L$, but that's just a matter of which order you write things. Otherwise it looks fine to me.

Comment: I am having a tough time showing that $\mathscr{L}$ has the finite intersection property. Could someone show me this?

Comment: Also, why do we have $p \in [x,y]$ for all $x \in A$ and $y \in U$. How do you know that every $x$ is in $A$ and every $y$ is in $U$? There doesn't seem to be much justification for many of the steps in the proof.

Comment: @Arthur can you please review my post now? I'm sure you'll find it better this time!

Comment: @user193319 please have a look at my post now. I've improved the proof. I'm sure you'll understand it now!

Comment: @SaaqibMahmood your proof seems correct and very clear, to me.

Comment: How to show $\bigcap_{[x,y] \in \mathscr{L}} [x,y] =\{ p\}$? and $p$ is independent of $a$ and $u$, i.e. if $a\neq a’ \in A$ and $u\neq u’\in U$, then $\bigcap \mathscr{L}’ =\{p\}$, where $\mathscr{L}’ =\{ [e,f]| e\in A, f\in U $ and $[e,f]\subseteq [a’,u’]\}$?