# Proof that Heine-Borel entails Completeness

Tags: real-analysis

I’m reading Royden’s *Real Analysis* and trying to solve problem 34 from the first chapter, which is to prove the equivalence of the Heine-Borel theorem and the completeness property (that every non-empty set bounded above has a least upper-bound).

I’ve looked at these questions on this topic:

[Prove Heine-Borel Theorem and Completeness Axiom are equivalent](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2363381/prove-heine-borel-theorem-and-completeness-axiom-are-equivalent)

[Prob. 1, Sec. 27, in Munkres' TOPOLOGY, 2nd ed: How to show that the compactness of every closed interval implies the least upper bound property?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1293310/prob-1-sec-27-in-munkres-topology-2nd-ed-how-to-show-that-the-compactness)

The first link has an answer that I’m concerned is not correct.  The argument I summarize as this:

Let $\emptyset \ne X\subset \mathbb{R}$ bounded above by $M$.  If $X$ has a maximum then this is the LUB, so assume $X$ has no maximum.  Then we open-cover $\overline{X}$ with the intervals $(-\infty, x)$ for every $x\in \overline{X}$.

Here is where I think the arguments starts to go wrong: I don’t think this is an open-cover for the set $\overline X$.  If $X=(0,1)$ then $\overline{X}=[0,1]$ and none of the open intervals contains 1.

Now the second answer at that link is, I think, very similar to the strategy pursued by the author in the second link.  Namely it uses the nested set theorem, which said briefly is the idea that if you have a bounded “quickly” shrinking chain of closed intervals, the infinite intersection contains a unique element.  However, that theorem was proved on the assumption of the completeness of the real numbers.  So for this argument I worry about circularity.

However, now I’m left not seeing a way forward.  My first instincts about how to do this were very similar to the first idea of making an open cover.  I tried making $M$ the upper limit of the closed interval, but then a finite open cover doesn’t clearly entail anything that I see.  The maximum open cover, so to speak, no longer is useful.  I thought about intersecting with the set of maxima, but then you don’t get a closed set ... or at least not one that’s useful.

I should note that the proof that Completeness entails Heine-Borel is obviously just the usual proof that Heine-Borel is true. So I have no question about that part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The argument does work. The only caveat is that you also need that $X$ is bounded below (otherwise, the closure won't be compact); but that's not a problem because you can just cut $X$ with some big enough interval.

In the linked answer, the argument is not as you say: you state it for $X$, but it should be $\overline X$. Note that $$\sup X=\sup\overline X,$$which is not hard to prove .

Now, if $\overline X$ has a maximum, then it has supremum. So now **you assume that $\overline X$ has no maximum**. In this latter case, indeed the sets $(-\infty,x)$ provide an open cover of $\overline X$; because if they don't, it means that there exists $m\in\overline X$ such that $m\geq x$ for all $x$, which is what a maximum is. Having obtained an open cover that does not admit a finite subcover, you contradict Heine Borel because $\overline X$, being closed and bounded, should be compact.

In your example $[0,1]$ lies in the first situation (it has a maximum), so the second situation does not apply. You will not find examples of the second situation; that's precisely what the argument shows: that there are no closed and bounded sets with no maximum.

Comment: I'm confused, I did state "for every $x\in\overline{X}$" and not for $X$.  Are you referring to something else?

Comment: Ok never mind, I see it.  It's that either $\overline{X}$ does or doesn't have a max, not $X$.    I guess I didn't consider the possibility of talking about $\overline{X}$ not having a max because intuitively we know that it does if it's bounded above.  But ok, I'll think more about the argument.

Comment: Exactly. It looks to me that your confusion stemmed from trying to find an example of the impossible case.